# algorithm which inputs n and outputs pair for each n-1 days

Tags: algorithm

Divide and algorithm question:each player must play exactly once against each of the n-1 opponents also at most one match per day show that if n is a power of 2, then it is possible to design a tournament that takes exactly n-1 days. do this by giving an algorithm which inputs n and outputs the list of players pairings for each of the n-1 days?so far i know that if n has to more than 2, and we are using similar to merge sort algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On day `d` (where `d` ranges from `1` to `n-1`), player `k` (where `k` ranges from `0` to `n-1`) plays player `k xor d`.

Some easy facts about this algorithm:

- if `n` is a power of `2`, `1 <= d <= n-1` and `0 <= k <= n-1` then `0 <= k xor d <= n-1` so the function `k, d -> k xor d` is a valid function from players and days to players.
- no player ever plays themselves, since `k xor d = k` implies `d = 0`.
- on any given day, this produces a pairing, since `k xor d xor d = k`.
- any given player never plays the same opponent twice, since `k xor d = x xor d'` implies `d = d'`.

Thus each player plays 1 opponent per day, and over `n-1` days, is matched against each opponent exactly once.

In code:

```
def matchings(n):
    for day in xrange(1, n):
        print 'Day', day
        for k in xrange(n):
            print 'Player', k, 'plays Player', k ^ day
        print

matchings(4)
```

Comment: But how you convert that into pseudo code and isnt the running time for that is o(n^2)??. also the way you describe it, it doesnt look like divide and conquer algorithm or merge sort. is that right?

Comment: @jsmith there's actual, working code in the question -- you can think of it as pseudo-code if you prefer. Yes, the running time is O(n^2) because the question asked for a schedule of n players over n-1 days -- that's already O(n^2) lines of output. You're right that the algorithm does not use a divide and conquer approach, nor does it look like merge sort.